# Can't add an asset from a .git folder

Tags: git, flutter

I'd like to retrieve and use commit hash that's stored in a .git folder (inside ORIG_HEAD file). To do this I registered my asset in pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/strings/
    - assets/images/
    - .git/ORIG_HEAD
```

and used

```
await rootBundle.loadString('.git/ORIG_HEAD');
```

to get the value from that file.

The iOS app works fine, but the android one throws an "**Unable to load asset**" error

I tried to duplicate the .git folder and remove a dot from the beginning. And it seems to be working (git file has been added as an asset - [flutter_assets in android apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls15b.png)). But this solution isn't a suitable one, because I'd like to have the relevant commit hash in place without any additional manipulations. Are there any workaround of such issue? Or it can be solved by adding pre-build scripts only?

Comment: Publishing your git repository in the application is not useful, of course Git repositories are excluded by default. Does it work if you add `!.git/ORIG_HEAD` to your `.gitignore`? This will un-ignore it. May not work for the `.git` directory itself.. but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: In this case I think a pre-build script might be the best option. [git info](https://pub.dev/packages/git_info) might help you achieve the same?

Comment: Thank you for the answer @PeterKrebs. This is the same option I've chosen

Comment: Okay I'll post it as an answer 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle has default exclusions that include the .git directory. In order to fix this you must update your settings.gradle file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner

DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude('**/.git')
DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude('**/.git/**')
```

I also updated the documentation for my package [git_info](https://pub.dev/packages/git_info) to include this.

Comment: Thank you. git_info was the exact package I tried to use. But it didn't work properly with android platform

Comment: @lesha-native I made that package lol. It didn't used to work, but I updated the README with the steps above to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Files *inside* a `.git` directory cannot be stored *in* a Git repository.  The reason is that the files inside a `.git` directory *are* a Git repository, or part of one, and no part of any Git repository can be stored inside a Git repository.<sup>1</sup>

The solution to your actual problem is simple: store the hash somewhere else.  You won't be able to have *Git* automatically update it, the way `.git/ORIG_HEAD` is automatically updated by Git commands that "change `HEAD` in a violent way" as it were, but you can choose when to update it manually yourself.  This is going to be a better idea anyway, because by choosing when *you* want the hash ID updated, you stop having it updated at any times you consider *wrong* ones.  It's possible that your idea of when it should be updated will exactly match Git's idea, now and forever, but that seems unlikely.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git enforces this by name, so if you *rename* a `.git` directory to some other name, you can start storing these files.  However, Git won't then use the `.git` directory as a repository—this is what made it safe for Git to store these files—so you'll need to create a new `.git` directory, which will be the actual repository, and now you're storing files that aren't part of a *repository*.  It's [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. Storing the hash somewhere else is the point I tend to follow

Answer (score 0):

The `.git` directory should not be accessed from builds. The directory is not meant to be part of the release, as it is the repository itself.

You can use a pre-build script as you mentioned.
There is also a package that can help you with information about your git repository:
[git_info](https://pub.dev/packages/git_info)

From the git_info example page:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:git_info/git_info.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

// This will not work unless you create a git repo in the example folder
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('git_info_example'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<GitInformation>(
          future: GitInfo.get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('Branch: ${snapshot.data!.branch}'),
                    Text('Hash: ${snapshot.data!.hash}'),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably somebody may be interested in additional script that stores latest commit hash (first 7 chars)

```
success="\033[32mThe latest commit hash has been successfully stored in
enter code hereassets:"
error="\033[31mError during saving latest commit hash in assets, the app might not work properly"
outputFile=assets/build-info/commit-hash

(
  head=$(<.git/HEAD) &&
  ref=$(echo $head | cut -d' ' -f2) &&
  hash=$(<.git/$ref) &&
  echo ${hash:0:7} > $outputFile &&
  echo -e "$success $(<$outputFile)"
) || echo -e $error
```

Save this code under the .sh file and execute it before running "run" or "build". The file with commit hash will be stored under "outputFile" path